# Using redux-saga with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-saga

I have a question about react-router: for example, I want to redirect from Create form to Edit form after called to create api (using redux-saga) successfully. How should I use react-router in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you include also [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) you can simply treat the page change as another redux action to call from saga (using the new `push` API).

Something like...

```js
yield put(push('your/route'))
```

Comment: this didn't work for me... I see this action being fired : type: "@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD" payload: {method: "push",args: "/myPageToRouteTo"} ... but there is no state change happening to the store

Comment: @OliverWatkins Is the state object returned, indeed, a new object? It's not enough, to update properties / values, a new object must be returned, to trigger a state change.

Are actions in place (success and error), to trigger state change? The below code handles a request. Upon response, it triggers a success or error action. The store handles state change immutability, via immer :

https://github.com/antonio-malcolm/interreaction/blob/master/src/state/health/HealthCheckWatcherWorkers.js

https://github.com/antonio-malcolm/interreaction/blob/master/src/state/health/HealthCheckStore.js

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add another package to implement this. I personally avoid using extra packages. ALl you have to do is passing the `history` object to saga through the action object.

Let's say I have a login component and if login successful I want to navigate:

Signin component:
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

```
const SignIn = ({ emailSignInStart, googleSignInStart, history }) => { 
   const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const { email, password } = userCredentials;

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    emailSignInStart({ email, password, history });
  };
   
   return (
    ......JSX HRE
    )
  }

  export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn));
```

in order to pass the "history" object if this is a component not a page wrap it with `withRouter` since it is functional component

then in saga function, you will have access to action object whose payload contains `history` object.

```
export function* signInWithEmail({ payload }) {
  try {
    console.log("I am in signin with email saga", payload.email);
    const { email, password, history } = payload;
    // an example for firebase authentication
    const { user } = yield auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    yield getSnapshotFromUserAuth(user);
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signInFailure(error));
  }
}
```